# how do I check in bash whether a file was created more than x time ago?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I want to check in linux bash  whether a file was created more than x time ago.

let's say the file is called text.txt and the time is 2 hours.

```
 if [ what? ]
 then
     echo "old enough"
 fi
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Only for modification time

```
if test `find "text.txt" -mmin +120`
then
    echo old enough
fi
```

You can use `-cmin` for change or `-amin` for access time.  As others pointed I don’t think you can track creation time.

Comment: you can drop 'test' and the backticks. This is analogous to 'if (test == true)' vs 'if (test)'

Comment: You're correct; I suppose I was thinking that `find` returned non-zero when no matches are found.

Comment: You can drop the backticks and do if test $(find text.txt -mmin +120)

Comment: @BroSlow look better: there is *no* "more than one" possible. Of course, `text.txt` is presumed not to be a directory.

Comment: @BroSlow it says “a file”. And flybywire liked that answer so obviously it was not a directory.

Comment: @kmkaplan Actually nevermind, I misinterpreted the command as having a `-name`. +1

Comment: @Alfe - you're missing a trailing ')' - and also bash expands '!' so watch out how excited you want to be in echo statements :-)

Comment: I prefer this syntax: `[ "$(find path/to/file -mmin +120)" ] && echo "it is old"`

Comment: you can also pass decimals of a minute for instance 6 seconds is 0.1

Comment: I am using centOs and it only works if I use `-mmin -120` instead of  `-mmin +120`. Maybe the logic is "greater than" instead of "less than"... ?

Answer (score 51):

I always liked using `date -r /the/file +%s` to find its age.

You can also do `touch --date '2015-10-10 9:55' /tmp/file` to get extremely fine-grained time on an arbitrary date/time.

Comment: I was looking for same thing today. Best!

Comment: Thanks. I landed on this SO question because I googled "how to print age of file bash." So this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks! with the only caveat that the above is a timestamp (not age) but can be used to calc the age like so   `let AGE=$(($(date +%s)-$(date -r /path/to/file +%s)))`  [with the assumption that created and never modified, or "age relative to mod"]

Comment: ```function file-age {
  FILE_CREATED_TIME=`date -r "$1" +%s`;
  TIME_NOW=`date +%s`;
  echo "$[ ${TIME_NOW} - ${FILE_CREATED_TIME} ]";
}
```

Comment: @turiyag Obligatory note that `$[ ]` is, if not *deprecated*, at least *old and less portable*, and one should use `$(( ))` instead; and backquotes are more fragile than `$( )`; and also hyphens in function names may not be fully portable. The essence of it is good, though!

Comment: This answer has some good information but does **not** answer the question.

Comment: ```file_age() {
    local created
    local now

    created=$(date -r "$1" +%s)
    now=$(date +%s)
    echo "$(( now - created ))"
}
```

Comment: 'date -r /the/file +%s'  is the file's "birthdate", not its "age".

Answer (score 34):

Using the `stat` to figure out the last modification date of the file, `date` to figure out the current time and a liberal use of bashisms, one can do the test that you want based on the file's last modification time<sup>1</sup>.

```
if [ "$(( $(date +"%s") - $(stat -c "%Y" "$somefile") ))" -gt "7200" ]; then
   echo "'$somefile' is older then 2 hours"
fi
```

While the code is a bit less readable then the `find` approach, I think its a better approach then running `find` to look at a file you already "found". Also, date manipulation is fun ;-)

---

1. As Phil correctly noted creation time is not recorded, but use `%Z` instead of `%Y` below to get "change time" which may be what you want.

**[Update]**

For mac users, use `stat -f "%m" "$somefile"` instead of the Linux specific syntax above

Comment: What shell are date and stat built in to? My bash (GNU, 3.2.48) doesn't have them.

Comment: oops, sorry. `stat` is not builtin - very bad of me, I'll fix.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen - I don't have a mac available. Can you please describe what doesn't work? Also, are you using bash? I know many Macists prefer zsh.

Comment: I've added a note for mac users.

Comment: @Guss right solution is to install coretutils with  brew. :-)

Comment: @ErikJohansson I prefer not to require installation of additional software when using the existing one works fine - this isn't Windows, you know ;-)

Comment: For people who want to use this but modify it, it would be good to know exactly what it is doing:
$(( $(date +"%s")  -- seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (Epoch)
$(stat -c "%Y" $somefile) ))  --  Time of last modification as seconds since Epoch
-gt "7200"  -- checks if the difference is greater than x number of seconds.

Comment: @Guss Thanks for updating the answer. This is now the best answer.

Comment: @Ian Clelland  stat and date are standard gnu tools, common on most linux installs https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html#stat-invocation https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation

Comment: You should always quote variables that might contain spaces or special characters, e.g. `"$somefile"`.  (It's the only parameter there that really needs quoting.)

Answer (score 17):

Creation time isn't stored.

What are stored are three timestamps (generally, they can be turned off on certain filesystems or by certain filesystem options):

- Last access time
- Last modification time
- Last change time

a "Change" to the file is counted as permission changes, rename etc. While the modification is contents only.

Answer (score 13):

Although ctime isn't *technically* the time of creation, it quite often is.

Since ctime it isn't affected by changes to the contents of the file, it's usually only updated when the file is created.  And yes - I can hear you all screaming - it's also updated if you change the access permissions or ownership...   but generally that's something that's done once, usually at the same time you put the file there.

Personally I always use mtime for everything, and I imagine that is what you want.  But anyway...   here's a rehash of Guss's "unattractive" bash, in an easy to use function.

```
#!/bin/bash
function age() {
   local filename=$1
   local changed=`stat -c %Y "$filename"`
   local now=`date +%s`
   local elapsed

   let elapsed=now-changed
   echo $elapsed
}

file="/"
echo The age of $file is $(age "$file") seconds.
```

Comment: This was useful, but it didn't work right away for OSX because stat is implemented differently on it. The only cross-system compatible way I found was to use perl. The script should work on Macs if you replace the corresponding line with this:

`local changed=$(perl -MFile::stat -e "print stat(\"${filename}\")->mtime")`   http://superuser.com/questions/427551/is-there-a-cross-nix-compatible-way-to-get-file-modified-timestamp

Comment: "Creation time" is a concept hard to grasp.  What does it mean for a copied file?  What for a moved file?  What if it was moved across a device border (so it got created anew, in a sense)?  What does it mean for a packaged and later unpackaged file?  Several answers are possible here and no consensus exists.  Mentioning the ctime is nice, though, but I wouldn't put it semantically near the vague concept of a "creation time".  Especially since a simple `chmod`, applied on the file, will nullify that idea.  But I can live with *you* doing that ;-)

Comment: @Alfe: You're missing the `+%s` from the second half

Comment: That age can be way shorter: `age() { echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(date -r "$1" +%s) )); }`  (Thanks to @Grizly for the correction!)

Comment: Actually it's better to use access time which is a creation time on all file systems mounted with `noatime` option (which is good for performance so you should use it). So just use `%X` instead of `%Y`.

Answer (score 9):

The find one is good but I think you can use anotherway, especially if you need to now how many seconds is the file old

`date -d "now - $( stat -c "%Y" $filename ) seconds" +%s`

using GNU date

Comment: use gstat, "brew install coreutils"

Answer (score 5):

Consider the outcome of the tool 'stat':

```
  File: `infolog.txt'
  Size: 694         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 11635578    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/     fdr)   Gid: ( 1000/     fdr)
Access: 2009-01-01 22:04:15.000000000 -0800
Modify: 2009-01-01 22:05:05.000000000 -0800
Change: 2009-01-01 22:05:05.000000000 -0800
```

You can see here the three dates for Access/modify/change. There is no
created date. You can only really be sure when the file contents were
modified (the "modify" field) or its inode changed (the "change"
field).

Examples of when both fields get updated:

"Modify" will be updated if someone concatenated extra information to
the end of the file.

"Change" will be updated if someone changed permissions via chmod.

Comment: granted, stat can tell you relevant information. But it will be quite tedious to parse in order to get what we want.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
file_age() {
    local filename=$1
    echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(date -r $filename +%s) ))
}

is_stale() {
    local filename=$1
    local max_minutes=20
    [ $(file_age $filename) -gt $(( $max_minutes*60 )) ]
}

if is_stale /my/file; then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [coreutils 8.31, glibc 2.28 and kernel version 4.11 or newer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119698/when-was-file-created/119699#119699), `stat` returns the creation date of a file.
To retrieve the creation date

```
file_creation_date=`stat -c '%w' text.txt`
```

We retrieve the time it was two hours ago

```
two_hours_ago=`date -u +"%F %T" -d '2 hours ago'`
```

And, we compare the two dates

```
if [[ $file_creation_date > $two_hours_ago ]]; then
    echo "older"
fi
```