# Test a file date with bash

Tags: bash, file, datetime, creation

I am trying to test how old ago a file was created (in seconds) with bash in an `if` statement. I need creation date, not modification.

Do you have any idea how to do this, without using a command like `find` with `grep`?

Comment: There are a number of commands you can use to do this and bash can call all of them. Why the aversion to using external commands? UNIX was built on the philosophy of tools doing one thing and one thing well.

Comment: will last modifiction time suffice - or do you need creation time?

Comment: Date of creation isn't stored on many often used filesystems. What filesystem do you use?

Comment: The problem would also be to get the time with standard tools that operate above VFS, no matter if the timestamp is stored or not. +1 for the only valid answer about creation timestamps...

Comment: Ext2FS / ReiserFS (Linux/Debian)

Comment: I'd prefer creation time

Comment: creation time isn't stored anywhere...so unless you store it yourself last modified is the best your going to get i'm afraid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the best answer I found at the time being, but it's only for the modification time :

```
expr `date +%s` - `stat -c %Y /home/user/my_file`
```

Comment: with %Z instead of %Y you get last change date (creation date as on my machine)

Answer (score 24):

I'm afraid I cann't answer the question for creation time, but for last modification time you can use the following to get the *epoch date*, in *seconds*, since *filename* was *last modified*:

```
date --utc --reference=filename +%s
```

So you could then so something like:

```
modsecs=$(date --utc --reference=filename +%s)
nowsecs=$(date +%s)
delta=$(($nowsecs-$modsecs))
echo "File $filename was modified $delta secs ago"

if [ $delta -lt 120 ]; then
  # do something
fi
```

etc..

**Update**
A more elgant way of doing this (again, modified time only): [how do I check in bash whether a file was created more than x time ago?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/552724/86263)

Answer (score 2):

If your system has `stat`:

```
modsecs=$(stat --format '%Y' filename)
```

And you can do the math as in **Joel**'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ls with --full-time

```
file1="file1"
file2="file2"
declare -a array
i=0
ls -go --full-time "$file1" "$file2" | { while read -r  a b c d time f
do    
  time=${time%.*}  
  IFS=":"
  set -- $time
  hr=$1;min=$2;sec=$3
  hr=$(( hr * 3600 ))
  min=$(( min * 60 ))  
  totalsecs=$(( hr+min+sec ))
  array[$i]=$totalsecs  
  i=$((i+1))
  unset IFS      
done
echo $(( ${array[0]}-${array[1]} ))
}
```